# Trying to switch URL of iframe YouTube video on click with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I have two divs. One contains a YouTube iframe video and the other contains a YouTube thumbnail. When the button is pressed, these are the intended steps:

-retrieve URL of the thumbnail

-replace URL of the iframe video with the URL of the YouTube video the thumbnail is from.

Here is the JSFiddle. It seems like it should work, but when I click the button I'm only getting a black screen. Can anyone offer advice? http://jsfiddle.net/jw1sw01v/1/

HTML

```
<div id="stage">
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/e-ORhEE9VVg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


<div class="slideYThumbnail">
        <img class="slideYThumbnailInside" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/kt0g4dWxEBo/0.jpg">
        </img>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.slideYThumbnail', function(event) {
        var change = $(this).find("img").attr("src").split("/");
        alert(change[4]);
        $("#stage > iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + change[4] + '"); 
});
```

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/jw1sw01v/2/ Concatenation was wrong!

Comment: `$("#stage > iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + change[4]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for directly on image

```
$(document).on('click', '.slideYThumbnailInside', function (event) {
    var change = $(this).attr("src").split("/");
    $("#stage > iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"change[4]);
            
});
```

Answer (score 2):

you have to remove single quote in js

```
$(document).on('click', '.slideYThumbnail', function(event) {
    var change = $(this).find("img").attr("src").split("/");
    alert(change[4]);
    $("#stage > iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + change[4] ); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this js instead of yours
JS:

```
$(document).on('click', '.slideYThumbnail', function (event) {
  var change = $(this).find("img").attr("src").split("/");
  alert(change[4]);
  $("#stage > iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"change[4]);
});
```

Working [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/sr4s3f9n/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the single quotes from your new video source concatenation like so:

```
 $("#stage > iframe").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/" + change[4]);
```